# Does the classical relativity supports elastic particles going faster than $c$?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

If we work in an experiment similar to that of Michelson-Morley and we assume that light is made up of small elastic particles, and we make light beams reflect multiple times from moving mirrors, could they, according to classical relativity, travel to
speeds much higher than $c$?

Any idea is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think they would?

Comment: There's no such thing, to my knowledge, as "classical relativity."  If you mean "does Newtonian mechanics lead to photons travelling at unlimited speed"  then the answer is "yes."  Since observation shows this doesn't happen,  we find that Special Relativity is consistent with observed behavior.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "Classical relativity" certainly exists. "Galilean relativity" is commonly called.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the full Michelson-Morley experimental setup to point to that conclusion. It is enought to have one mirror moving at a velocity $v$ with respect to an observer and a photon moving at velocity $c$ in the opposite direction (one arm of the Michelson-Morley interferometer).

If the momentum transfer from the photon to the mirror is negligible (since the mirror could have an arbitrarily large mass) then, after reflection, the photon would have a velocity $v+c > c$. So yeah, in classical non-relativistic mechanics this is possible.

In fact, you don't even need a mirror to "bounce" off to experience this faster than light behaviour if [Galilean relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) was true. Just by having a photon moving in one direction and the observer moving in the opposite at a speed $v$, the observer would see the photon moving at $v+c$. No reflection, no physical interaction, just a photon and the observer passing by.

But remember, this is not what happens in reality. If you walk in the opposite direction of a light beam, you are going to see the photons moving at $c$, and if you go "with the beam", you still are going to see the photons moving at $c$. Galilean transformations don't hold in reality. The true relative transformations you have to apply are the [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation), from which you would never see anything traveling faster than $c$ (in any of these scenarios).